# Cual es la palabra en español para esta expresión facial?

Tags: selección-de-palabras

## ¿Cuál es la palabra para la emoción que expresa esta persona?

[image: a disgruntled facial expression from rage comics]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Spanish looks like some sort of machine translation, is very bad and makes no sense at all.

Comment: **A mis colegas**: Los ingleses tienen una expresión idiomática muy interesante que se aplica al caso que tenemos aqui: to take the piss. Eso lo que este señor esta haciendo y vosotros están cayendo en su trampa.

Comment: I am leaving this question visible because, even though it is clear trolling, it has several well-received answers. Other trolling questions by this user have been deleted. Samuel, any further trolling questions (such as nonsensical text, very easy questions with just a line of text and an unhelpful image, or absurd claims that something has a sexual meaning) will be immediately deleted from now on.

Answer (score 3):

realizando una búsqueda inversa de la imagen, con Google, el meme parece recibir el nombre "Are you f***** kidding me?" Esto podría traducirse como "¿me estás vacilando?"

Sin embargo, en español creo que sería más natural decir, simplemente, "**¿en serio?"**, con significado de "really?"

Y como apuntan otras respuestas, se sobreentiende un tono de decepción, pereza mental, o ausencia de diversión.

Answer (score 2):

### **Sr. Malauva**

[image]

**P.D.** Cada persona interpretará de forma distinta está emoción según su experiencia.

Comment: Opino igual, las experiencias personales e incluso la cultura de una sociedad podrían darle distinto significado, podría ser alguien enojado, aburrido, o muy concentrado.

Answer (score 1):

Esa imagen expresa sin duda expresa "decepción", colocandolo en un contexto más real...

Estás esperando el resultado de una acción de una persona que previamente tu sabes que lo va a hacer mal, entonces estás "decepcionado" pero al mismo tiempo sabías es resultado de y qué no vale ni la pena discutir o intentar entender el motivo.